# How to return first x words in a file which are greater than a certain cut_off value using while loop in python?

Tags: python-2.7

How do I return the first x words from a file which has some content which is greater in length than a particular `cut_off` value? If file has less words than `x` then the function should be able to return all words in the file which is greater than `cut_off`:

My code is:

```
def function(filename , x , cut_off):

output="" 

index=0
myfile=open(filename)

text=myfile.read()

words=text.split()

while(index < x):

  if(len(words[index])>cut_off):

    output+=words[index]

  index+=1

return output
```

I am still soooo confused!
Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following also:
Keep a counter = 0
1. Read the file line by line. 
2. Split each line into a list of words.
3. Loop through each of these words and compare with the cut_off. 
4. If the word satisfies the cut off, increment the counter. 
5. Now check if the counter is less than x or not. 
6. If it is less, add the word to a list and keep looping to the next word or line.
7. If equal, return the list of the words.

This takes care of each of your problems.

Let me know in case you need a proper code for this.

Comment: Thanks :) can u give me a code for this? That would be amazingly helpful :)